What is this IC marked '63M44P .420'?
I have an IC in an SMD package with 6 pins.
It is used in switching power supply.
It is marked as:

First row: 63M44P
Second row: .420

Can you tell me what this integrated circuit is?

I identified it for you, but please take a picture next time.

It's an On-Bright OB2263MP PWM Controller.


(Source: ceneo.pl)
